# Changing the FormView record while in insert mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formview

I have 2 ObjectDataSource's - 1 for the GridView and 1 for the FormView.

I enabled selection on the GridView and all is well; the page loads, you select a record, and the FormView populates with the record.

However, once the FormView is in Insert mode, when I select a record on the GridView, it is not changing back to display the record I selected.

Where could I handle this in the code, as I don't see how to access the "Enable Selection" on the GridView in code behind?

What I have tried

```
protected void grdSearchGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formGroupInput.DefaultMode = FormViewMode.ReadOnly;
    formGroupInput.DataBind();
}

protected void grdSearchGroup_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    formGroupInput.DefaultMode = FormViewMode.ReadOnly;
    formGroupInput.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to solve your problem is to handle the GridView's SelectedIndexChanging method, and set the FormView back to read-only mode (that way you can see the records details in the FormView like you want).

```
protected void yourGridView_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourFormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
}
```

Note that you must call the FormView's [`ChangeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.changemode.aspx) method in order to update the mode.  Just setting the DefaultMode property is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I have tried this but When the formview is in InsertMode you have to hit cancel for hit to actually go back to read only it does not change automatically?

Comment: @Henry In the code samples you added to your question, you are doing it the wrong way.  You are just setting the "DefaultMode" property; look at my code, you need to call the "ChangeMode" method to actually change the FormView's mode.

Comment: @Henry No need to feel like a dummy =)  Believe me, I've done far dumber things.  Good luck!